# The following operation or use case is not yet supported in SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

Got this error today:

```
System
USER_ERROR
24/3/2021
11:08 AM
-System-
The following operation or use case is not yet supported in SuiteScript: API getSessionRecordObject() on nlobjContext, script ID:(blurred just in case) bundles:[]
```

To add a little bit of context I'll say that the logic behind these scripts:
Main script is a 1.0 Suitlet, calling another 1.0 Suitlet, which calls a 2.0 Suitlet, which calls a 2.0 library. I know it's kind of confusin but the only thing that comes to my mind is that it's a version error. Using something from 2.0 in 1.0 or viceversa, but as far as I checked it's not.
Any other ideas on what it could be coming from?

Thanks!

Comment: Which one of your scripts is the error coming from?

Comment: It was coming from the 2nd 1.0 suitlet, it wouldn't let us JSON.parse some values so we had to end up working around it.
With this information if anyone comes across this, be careful with using 1.0 functions in 2.0, and using JSON.parse in some NetSuite objects, sometimes it doesn't go well but the errors won't let you know it was because of your parsing.
Take care!